# Hiding the main layout of Custom Dialog

Tags: android

I have made layout for custom dialog, it has inside two imageview. I want to show both Imageview when dialog appear. and i want to hide the main layout of my xml file I have used "#00000000" as background:color, but it is not working.
Is there any way to do the same?

Thanks.

Here is my layout. I have taken screen shot please have a look i want to hide the border which are showing in image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#00000000">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_closeimage" android:src="@drawable/product_zoom_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"></ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-5dip" android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" android:layout_marginRight="20dip">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_ProductZoom" android:src="@drawable/index"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 ></ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wOl1.png)

Comment: Your custom layout looks quite strange; why do you have two embedded LinearLayouts(even with the same id `@+id/linearLayout1`!) in the main Linearlayout, each with an ImageView, if you only want one ImageView for this dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Adinias comment is correct, your layout has quite some redundancy. You also say that you only want to show an imageview, but your layout contains two imageviews. If you only want to show one imageview, then your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img_ProductZoom" android:src="@drawable/index"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

If you want to show two ImageViews, use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#00000000">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_closeimage" android:src="@drawable/product_zoom_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_ProductZoom" android:src="@drawable/index"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your current layout looks the way it does because you have specified the layout to take as much space as possible with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. Try to use `wrap_content` as height and width instead.

Comment: Please see the Image Description I have to show an Image and a close button as showing in Image Description. and redundancy because of getting the expected result. Using above code,it will not show the expected view. Thanks